# Remove old reports from IBM Cognos UI for BI

Tags: shell, db2, cognos-bi, cognos-10

We have some old reports which are not being used anymore by the business and wish to remove/archive these.

I have 2 queries related to this:

a) What is the best way to find if a report has not been used for the past 12+ months?

b) Is there any simple way of moving the reports no longer being used (not used for > 12 months) to a different location (i.e. new folder), while keeping the folder structure intact?

We have searched for solutions on the web, but have not been able to find an automated solution for this. as the number of reports which we have figured out is in the range of ~5000, we are searching for an automated way to work this out.

Would running an SQL query on the server (physical machine) be advisable? If we run this query on the content store, we wish to figure out the column/field on which the actual report lies (in the below query have used , but not sure if such a field or query can be used):

```
update <table> set <report_path>='/content/folder[@name='Home']/folder[@name='Report']/report[@name='ABC012 - My Report']' where <report_path>='/content/folder[@name='Home']/folder[@name='Archive_test']/report[@name='ABC012 - My Report']'
```

Would this kind of a query work?

If not, can anyone suggest a way on which we can move reports to a single  folder on the same Cognos box? (we are using Cognos 10, with DB2 and Netezza)

Comment: This is my bread as a Cognos consultant :) You can write a query against Cognos DB (not audit). Or try using advanced search on the portal.

Comment: Have you got Cognos Audit package installed? What DB is your Content manager using?

Comment: @Stoleg: Yes, we have the Cognos Audit Manager installed. We are using DB2 as the DB for the Content Manager. We do not have the Cognos SDK installed though. Also, want something which allows for the query to be run quickly and through a Shell script or SQL scripts, and can be automated to run at a scheduled time.

Comment: Check this out: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cfpm/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cra_id4425SampleAuditReports.html - it gives simple audit model for CM database. It is independent from DB type you use. it gives Report Studio reports for audit. You can schedule them via Event Studio.